# How to find a upper triangular matrix similar to A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Given a matrix A how do you find a matrix Q such that Q inverse A Q is upper traingular, in complex. I know that it is possible and the proof uses a induction argument but i don't see how to find such a matrix when dealing with an actual example. Can someone possibly give me some advice on how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean by hand or by computer?

Comment: by hand say for a 3x3 or 4x4 matrix is there like a method of doing this as in the case of diagonal matrices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

Jordan Canonical form would give you corresponding upper triangular matrix